# JQuery nested sortable chrome issues

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-ui-sortable

I've been developing a file-tree like widget using [Johnny's extended jquery sortable](http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/), which handles nested sortables better than standard JQuery.

I have an issue with reinitializing the tree with new data. There is no problem in firefox, but chrome acts up. [A minimal example can be seen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXKqAd?editors=1010) (or [on jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/j1n5g0jn/))

In the onDrop callback, the tree is re-initialized. For brevity, all that happens is a `console.log`, but in my actual example, data is being POSTed to the server via ajax, and the response has new data to update the tree with.

So, Firefox is happy with this solution, but in chrome, once I drag-and-drop once, and the tree is re-initialized, the next drag will fail with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined`

- ✓ Firefox
- ✓ Internet explorer
- ✕ Chrome

Comment: Checked on linux and windows on multiple computers. Dig you drag and drop twice to trigger the re-init?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will destroy the `sortable` every time before you init that element it will work:

```
function init(e) {
    // First of all - we destroy the sortable
    $('ul').sortable('destroy');

    var root = $('<ul></ul>')
    createNodes(root)
    e.html(root)
    root.sortable({
        group: 'foo',
        onDrop: function ($item, container, _super, event) {
            // These two lines are default behaviour of the plugin
            $item.removeClass(container.group.options.draggedClass).removeAttr("style");
            $("body").removeClass(container.group.options.bodyClass);

            console.log('Updating')
            init(e)
        }
    })
}
```

**Working snippet**:

```js
function createNodes(e) {
  var foo = $('<li>Foo<ul></ul></li>');
  var bar = $('<li>Bar<ul></ul></li>');
  var baz = $('<li>Baz<ul></ul></li>');
  bar.find('ul').append(baz);
  e.append(foo, bar);
}

function init(e) {
  // First of all - we destroy the sortable
  $('ul').sortable('destroy');
  
  var root = $('<ul></ul>')
  createNodes(root)
  e.html(root)
  root.sortable({
    group: 'foo',
    onDrop: function ($item, container, _super, event) {
        // These two lines are default behaviour of the plugin
        $item.removeClass(container.group.options.draggedClass).removeAttr("style");
        $("body").removeClass(container.group.options.bodyClass);

        console.log('Updating')
        init(e)
    }
  })
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  init($('#myroot'))
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/js/jquery-sortable.js"></script>
<div id="myroot">
</div>
```

Comment: You are correct. Thanks. To win the bounty, you need to provide more information on why this is true for Chrome and not Firefox. Is it a garbage collection difference?

Comment: I'll try and check it for you :)

Comment: ah man, the bounty expired, so it was automatically assigned to you. Didn't know it worked that way.

Comment: No sure what you expected. I gave the correct answer, so it only makes sense that I will get the bounty. Did you not intend to award the bounty?

Comment: I wanted the bounty to go to someone who could explain why the browsers behave differently. But its not important, I suppose.